# C++ Bool not returning true or false using pointers

Tags: c++, list, pointers, boolean

Im trying to implement a list of nodes on my own using pointers. 
So ive this on my class as private:

```
class cj_enters {

private:
struct node{
  node* next;
  node* prev;
  int info;
}; 

node* first;
node* last;
node* actual;

int size;

public:
.
.
};
```

And im trying to implement this method:

```
bool cj_enters:: operator==(const cj_enters& B) const{
  bool cerca = true;
  node* aux = first;
  while(aux != NULL and cerca){
      if(!B.conte(aux->info)) // this method is working and it tells if object B has the info somewhere of the current node info(aux).
      {
          cerca = false;
      }
      else aux = aux -> next;
  }

return cerca;
}
```

So I don't know why but this method is returning me strange values like 244 or so when I compare two of these objects, it doesn't matter if they are the same or they are not.

Why is that? Thanks

Comment: `node* aux = first;` and `delete aux;` doesn't seem like it's going to lead to defined behavior...

Comment: Could you please specify what this operator== is supposed to do? Why a delete statement inside operator== ?
Also, avoid putting the else statement in the same line and without parenthesis.

Comment: If this and B have the same "first" node, then their data is identical, however they also have some traversal state, so do you want to know if they are both at the same point in iteration or not?  Or can you just return this.first == B.first;

Comment: operator == is suposed to compare between two objects of the class if they contain the same info in their nodes, so the size must be equal ofc.

Comment: @KennyOstrom They dont shate the same nodes, we are just comparing the info on their nodes.

Comment: Do you mean the boolean returned by this function has the value 204 (interpreted as true)?

Comment: So you just want to know if this.first.info == B.first.info, and then repeat for the next nodes

Comment: No matter what you do with comparisons and traveral won't matter anyway, because you delete your tree for no reason.  You should not delete unless it is directly paired with new.

Comment: I tried to erase the delete line but it is still not working. And @LorenzoBelli, the value returned has random values different to 1 or 0, and they interprete those as true always..

Comment: What makes you think this function "returns 244"?

Comment: This code is extremely unclear.

Comment: well ive a main.cpp then there I do:
bool x = cj == cj2;
cout<<x;

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Answer (score -1):

If `first==NULL` then `aux==NULL` and then you call `delete aux`.

Comment: You don't call delete unless it's paired with new.  Just because you "can" get away with "delete nullptr" doesn't mean you should.

Comment: Yeah but first is not NULL!

Comment: Still I deleted the "delete aux" and it is still not working! :/

Comment: The variable `cerca` is set to `true` or `false` in this method, there are no possible values. I exclude that your compiler set `true` to a random positive integer. You could try to check the value of `cerca` at every iteration of while loop. I suspect someone is overwriting your variable on the stack (for example the method `conte`).

Comment: @Burnsed: No it doesn't. Why do you think it does? How are you determining that? Your method of determining that is broken.

Comment: @LorenzoBelli Could u please be more specific?